# Pandas dataframe to csv with classes

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have tried many different dataframe statments but cannot seem to get this output into a csv format via pandas. I think I'm making a simple mistake but I cannot figure out exactly what.  It is the output from an nltk classifier. Here is my output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'neg': set([3, 6, 8, 15, 21, 23, 38, 40, 44, 46, 47, 51, 52, 53, 55, 58, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 80, 81, 82, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 90, 91, 92, 94, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 114, 115]), 'neutral': set([50, 4, 5, 93, 95, 43, 12, 45, 14, 79, 49, 37, 67, 113, 59, 60, 29, 31]), 'pos': set([0, 1, 2, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 39, 41, 42, 48, 54, 56, 57, 61, 69, 83, 89])})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what the output should be, since the dict holds sets, but this should work:

```
pandas.DataFrame({k: list(v) for k, v in your_output.items()}).to_csv('yourfile.csv')
```

Comment: I feel like such an amateur because i cannot figure pandas out but I did what you said as well as a few variations and I keep getting this error message:

Comment: ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: predictSets = collections.defaultdict(set)   
   
 for i, (features, label) in enumerate(predictFeatures):
         predicted = classifier.classify(features)
         predictSets[predicted].add(i)

Comment: I'm sorry about the formatting, I'm obviously a novice.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

pd.DataFrame makes matrix. If you pass a dict it will make columns from `dict.keys()` and for each `[i, col]` element assign i-th value `dict[col][i]`. It's why you can't pass dict with different value's lengths.

in your task you may do something like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=dd.keys())
for col, indexes in dd.items():
    for index in indexes:
        data.loc[index, col] = 1

data.fillna(0) # fill other values with 0
```

or

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sentiment'])


for col, indexes in dd.items():
    for index in indexes:
        data.loc[index, 'sentiment'] = col
```

where `dd` is result of nltk classifier